# How to git clone all submodules (using --recursive) except one?

Tags: git, github, clone

Is there a way to use `git clone --recursive` to clone a project including all of it's submodules, except one (manually specified) submodule? Thank you!

Comment: No, if you use `--recursive` Git will attempt to clone all submodules. You can *remove* the one you don't want, or clone without `--recursive` and then `update --init` the ones you do want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git clone --recurse-submodules` takes an optional pathspec.  This pathspec can be negative (e.g., `!*.c`) to match all files but a particular path.  See `gitglossary(7)` for the form of pathspecs.  You may need to specify `--recurse-submodules=.` and the add an additional negative pathspec version as well.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! How to specify both a positive and a negative qualifier at the same time? `|` Regex perhaps?

Comment: You can pass multiple `--recurse-submodules` arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The example below will clone a repo and all submodules except the one specified. You can use wildcards here.

`--recurse-submodules=:!path\to\submodule`